# How to backup linked servers with SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, database-backups, database-restore

I want to backup/restore my data which is distributed in some linked servers, which are connected or linked in a central server. How can I do this?

I'm using SQL Server 2012 in all my nodes.

Answer (score 6):

you can use the remote machine to run sp_executesql command within the dynamic SQL.

```
exec server.master.dbo.sp_executesql 'BACKUP DATABASE DBNAME1 to disk='\\Server\Share\backupfilename.bak''
```

Comment: Well... You're right. I was thinking something crazy like create a backup file with the data from all my nodes, but that would be impossible to recover in each different node, later.

Comment: Remember to enable `RPC OUT` in the linked server properties to enable this.

Comment: @Leon Armstorng, Great answer, thanks.  Could you please revisit/correct your 2 Options as they both are identical other than [brackets]. It feels as if you were going to show 2 different ways/options of achieving this.